# Cooking salmon quenelles souse-vide?

Tags: sous-vide, salmon

Is it possible to successfully adapt the recipe below to use fresh salmon and to cook this sous-vide rather than poaching? I was thinking of freezing the pre-formed mixture so it doesn't compress when I vacuum seal it. Would cooking this in a sous-vide bath at 63C for 60 minutes be sufficient cooking time? I don't want the quenelles to end up rubbery or tough.

**Original recipe:**

https://youtu.be/Or0dCoJNmqM?si=Ao0illxnQwAVECFy

**New ingredients:**

- 250g salmon
- 2 eggs
- 150ml double (heavy whipping) cream
- 60g butter
- Salt and pepper to season

Answer (score 1):

The quenelles will not hold together when you vac-pack them.  They'll just go squish.  They're quite delicate, and like most quenelle recipes this one relies on the mixture going straight from the spoons into boiling water to make sure that they start cooking before they can start coming apart.

Also, the original is a recipe for whitefish.  Salmon is considerably higher in fat than most whitefish, so that would affect the texture, possibly enough to cause them to disintegrate.

Comment: Your initial point I was hoping to negate by freezing. I hadn't considered your latter point, would adding a choux pastry base copensate for that? Some older quenelle recipies have that included.

Comment: I wouldn't expect freezing them to work either.  To make quenelles work, they really need to be hit with rapid heat from the outside, so that they cook before they can start to come apart.  That means simmering water or hot oil.  If you freeze them, they're still going to be heating too slow to set.

Comment: Not sure which issue you're addressing with the choux?  The salmon fat or the lack of sturdiness?